# How do I fix this Powershell FTP Upload Error

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that has been running for a few years already without fail, suddenly it began returning an error:

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Nothing has been changed on the client or server side except for perhaps windows updates.

Following is the code:

```
$ServerName = 'ftp.myserver.com'
$UserName = 'MyUsername'
$Password = 'MyPassword'

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $Password)

$srcFile = 'C:\TWD\AC.DBF'
$dstFile = 'AC.DBF'

$URI = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$ServerName/$dstFile”)
$WebClient.UploadFile($URI, $srcFile)

$srcFile = 'C:\TWD\ITEMS.DBF'
$dstFile = 'ITEMS.DBF'

$URI = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$ServerName/$dstFile”)
$WebClient.UploadFile($URI, $srcFile)
```

Comment: Change the curly quotes `“”` in the code and use straight ones. So called _smart-quotes_ may look nice in Word but can play havoc in code.

Answer (score 0):

Http 5xx error codes are server side.  If you haven't touched your script,  the problem doesn't lie there.  Check the server if you have the permissions to, or contact the administrator to confirm that endpoint still exists

Comment: But when I use filezilla or even ftp through my browser it works. Also I copied the script onto another computer and it uploaded the files successfully. I am only getting this error on this computer. What can it possibly be?

Comment: Hmm this I can't be too sure sorry. The code provided appears to be perfect. This would be more of an infrastructure/networking issue.